# ocLazyLoad angular load js file synchronously

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lazy-loading, oclazyload

Here my code.

```
var app = angular.module('app', [ 'oc.lazyLoad', 'ui.router',
            'ncy-angular-breadcrumb' ]);

    app.config([ '$ocLazyLoadProvider', function($llp) {
        $llp.config({
            debug : true
        });
    } ]);

    app.config([ '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider',
            function($sp, $locationProvider) {
                for (var i = 0; i < config.length; i++) {
                    var obj = config[i];
                    $sp.state(obj.state, {
                        url : obj.url,
                        templateUrl : obj.html,
                        ncyBreadcrumb : {
                            label : obj.label,
                            parent : obj.parents
                        },
                        resolve : {
                            load : loadDeps(obj.js)
                        },
                        data : {
                            pageTitle : obj.pageTitle
                        }
                    });

                }
                $sp.state('otherwise', {
                    url : '*path',
                    controller : function($state) {
                        $state.go("terminal");
                    }

                });

                function loadDeps(deps) {
                    return [ '$ocLazyLoad', function($ll) {
                        return $ll.load(deps);
                    } ];
                }
            } ]);
```

It worked. But my problem is loading multi js file. Example my first js must compile before second js. But lazyload sometimes load second js before although I had ordered file. So I get error. Can you help me.